# React app deployed on Netlify shows source files in browser inspect sources

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, netlify

I recently deployed a React app to Netlify by uploading the build folder to their platform. However, when I inspect the sources in the browser, I can still see all of the source files from my src directory, including all of my React components and JavaScript files as it is including the minified JS also. Based on my research, it seems like the build process should remove all of the unnecessary source files and assets from the final build, so I'm not sure why I'm still able to see them in the browser. Is there something I'm missing in my build process or in my Netlify setup? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. Just add .env to your project directory

`GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`